# Performance options

Tags: hardware, ssd, thunderbolt, mac-mini

I have a 2011 Mac mini and don't want to buy a new mini. It has 12gb ram and a 128gb PNY SSD which reads and writes in the 480mbps range. I'm looking for ways to speed it up, and I've done the basics like blowing out dust to reduce heat throttling etc. My ram pressure is really low since I only do light business apps such as Word, etc.

One thought I had was using its Thunderbolt 2 port (via [thunderbolt 3/2 apple adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter) and an [NVMe enclosure](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VXP2WLB) to plug in an external [NVMe SSD](https://www.pny.com/CS3030-M-2-NVMe-SSD?sku=M280CS3030-250-RB&CURRENT_NAV_ID=b83c9ac0-e251-454c-b078-3bbd37ce1ff5)) and booting from that instead. I know that my Mac only supports Thunderbolt and therefore 20gbps, but that'll be better than SATA since its 4x as fast, right? My goal here is to make it feel as snappy as possible.

Comment: Yes, the NVMe SSD might make it faster (though not by a lot, as there are diminishing returns for random reads & writes, especially considering the the overhead of Thunderbolt (not sure how much, I know USB is pretty bad and TB is better, but I've not personally tried a TB boot drive).

Comment: I guess what it comes down to is lower latency vs faster overall throughput, I'm not sure which method would be better for system stability.